# How do I write this sql query in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Here's the diagram :

[image: Diagram]

I have 3 tables:

1. Aya
2. Juz
3. Page

`Aya` has two foreign keys:

1. PageId
2. JuzId

I want to write a query to know how many pages are there in each Juz (indicated by yellow line in the diagram)

**I have tried :**

```
select juzid, count(pageid) as page_count
from ayas
group by juzid
```

but that gives me how may `aya`s are there in each Juz. And not how many Pages.

Comment: U peaple really need to write some comments before u downmark.

Comment: Hover your mouse in the downmark, it explains why. Normally, only 1 rep users post questions asking for code *without* showing what did they try, the famous "what have you tried". See [ask]

Comment: `SELECT juzid, COUNT(DISTINCT pageid) cnt FROM aya
GROUP BY juzid`?

Comment: Excellent ! Please put that as an answer !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the associations are one-to-many, you'll need to count *distinct* pages per juz;

```
SELECT juzid, COUNT(DISTINCT pageid) cnt 
FROM aya 
GROUP BY juzid
```